# Prevent metro app from going to background

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1

Is there any way by which I can prevent a windows metro app from going to background since it goes in suspended state when in backgroud?
Else how can I show a alert message when I am trying to put app in the background?

Comment: This is probably an XY problem.  Why do you think you need to prevent your app from being suspended?

Answer (score 1):

Not programmatically: apps cannot override the user's choice here.

Once the app's window is deactivated it is too late for it to show an alert message.

From a system configuration standpoint the [Assigned Access](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/assigned-access) feature allows an admin to set up kiosk with a single app which the user can't switch away from.

Comment: You could display a toast notification from the app’s suspending event; this is a technique I’ve used to warn the user that the long running operation they’ve instigated has been cancelled because the app has been suspended.